# Trying to increment values of the following colums using CASE statements

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is the code i have wriiten but when i execute its throwing wrong syntax error, Can I know what mistake I have done, Thank you

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN RATING = 'VERY_POOR' THEN 1 ELSE 0
   END 'VERYPOOR',
   WHEN RATING = 'POOR' THEN 1 ELSE 0
   END 'POOR',
   WHEN RATING = 'AVERAGE' THEN 1 ELSE 0
   END 'AVERAGE',
   WHEN RATING = 'GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE 0
   END 'GOOD',
   WHEN RATING = 'VERY_GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE 0
   END 'VERYGOOD'
+--------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------+-----------+
| RESPONSEDATE | VERY_POOR | POOR | AVERAGE | GOOD | VERY_GOOD | CSAT_RATING | CATEGORY_WEIGHTAGE | CATEGORYNAME   | CSATSCORE |
+--------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------+-----------+
| 2018-04-03   |         0 |    0 |       1 |    0 |         0 |           3 |                  0 | Overall Rating |         3 |
| 2018-04-03   |         0 |    0 |       0 |   32 |         0 |           4 |                  0 | Overall Rating |         4 |
| 2018-04-03   |         0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |        28 |           5 |                  0 | Overall Rating |         5 |
| 2018-04-04   |         0 |    0 |       6 |    0 |         0 |           3 |                  0 | Overall Rating |         3 |
| 2018-04-04   |         0 |    0 |       0 |   44 |         0 |           4 |                  0 | Overall Rating |         4 |
| 2018-04-04   |         0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |        32 |           5 |                  0 | Overall Rating |         5 |
| 2018-04-05   |         0 |    0 |       2 |    0 |         0 |           3 |                  0 | Overall Rating |         3 |
| 2018-04-05   |         0 |    0 |       0 |   14 |         0 |           4 |                  0 | Overall Rating |         4 |
| 2018-04-05   |         0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |        11 |           5 |                  0 | Overall Rating |         5 |
+--------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------+----------
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you include sample data and expected output? What is the syntax error? Ultimately you're not nesting your `CASE` statements properly, but it's difficult to determine what the expected behavior is.

Comment: + is an arithmetic operator and is inappropriate here . I am not clear what you are trying to do can you illustrate by adding sample data and expected result as text to the question.

Comment: Give us a sample dataset and your sample result

Comment: Ignore the RESPONSEDATE column here

Comment: @kchason Thanks the syntax error was that i was not neting the case statements.

Comment: You have enriched your question - but sadly not in a useful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CASE` syntax should be like the following:

```
CASE 
    WHEN Condition1 THEN Value1
    WHEN Condition2 THEN Value2
    ELSE Value3
END
```

If you need to write several `CASE` then you need to repeat whole structure (with different column alias if you want).

```
SELECT

    CASE 
        WHEN Condition1 THEN Value1
        WHEN Condition2 THEN Value2
        ELSE Value3
    END 'FirstCase',

    CASE 
        WHEN Condition1 THEN Value1
        WHEN Condition2 THEN Value2
        ELSE Value3
    END 'SecondCase',

    CASE 
        WHEN Condition1 THEN Value1
        WHEN Condition2 THEN Value2
        ELSE Value3
    END 'ThirdCase'

FROM
    YourTable
```

Your problem is that you are missing the keyword "`CASE`" after your first `CASE`.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN RATING = 'VERY_POOR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'VERYPOOR',
    CASE WHEN RATING = 'POOR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'POOR',
    CASE WHEN RATING = 'AVERAGE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'AVERAGE',
    CASE WHEN RATING = 'GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'GOOD',
    CASE WHEN RATING = 'VERY_GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'VERYGOOD'

-- FROM ....
```